# How to create a global variable of counter that lasts 12 hours?

Tags: java, android, timer, counter

I am working on an application where user are limited to view only 10 profiles per day (12 hours). So I want to create a global variable which is set to 10 start of each cycle. When user checks out 1 profile it is decremented by 1. When the counter is 0, I'll be showing a message of limit reach. And this counter is revised after 12 hours.

What should be the approach in doing this?

Comment: see `SharedPreferences` - the docs say: `"The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed)."`

Comment: use shared preference

Comment: thanks, and how to keep track of 12 hour cycle?

Comment: @greenapps you better use that funny lines somewhere else on facebook

Comment: aahha postman. within a day. good service.

Answer (score 0):

So you can store both global vars in shared prefs or in local db(realm, etc).
Simply, store two variables: profiles counter and time of last update. So u can check if it is already 12 hours past the last update and allow user to get updated.